# How to only fetch the headers and the effectiveUri of a website using GuzzleHttp?

Tags: php, symfony, request, guzzle

I'm using GuzzleHttp and I'm building a function which fetch a couple of things from a website.

I want to know the status code the user gets when he is redirected and I want to know the URL the user is redirected to, for example www.domain.org when the user goes to domain.org.

Right now I do it like this:

```
$response = $client->head($url, [
            'on_stats' => function (TransferStats $stats) use (&$effectiveUrl) {
                $effectiveUrl = $stats->getEffectiveUri();
            }
        ]);
```

But the problem is, I also fetch the html page this way. This gives me some unnecessary overload. I think the "HEAD" request is turned into a "GET" request because of the redirect and because of this, GuzzleHttp also returns the html page in the response. I only need the effectiveUri and the status code, is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: You should disable redirects first. See this: https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/http-redirects.html#disabling-redirects

Comment: @DamirKasipovic But if I disable redirects, I don't know which URL the user is redirected to. I need to know the EffectiveUri.

Comment: Yes, but you can read redirect header instead?

Comment: Maybe that is a solution. But sometimes a website redirects the user a couple of times. For example first a redirect to another domain and then the www. redirect, what happens then? The redirect header will only contain the first redirect header right?

Comment: That is true but you could get the redirect url and get its headers then, maybe in a loop while there are redirect headers present.

Comment: It doesn't feel like the most efficient solution, but it's better than all the unnecessary overload. I will look further and maybe use this solution later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157483/discussion-between-roberto-geuke-and-damir-kasipovic).